# Execute a function when user has stopped typing in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-1.6

I am using below library to use autocomplete directive in my module for AngularJS!.
[https://github.com/JustGoscha/allmighty-autocomplete]

I want to execute a function when user has stopped typing, is there a way I can do this?

Comment: I'd imagine you could use [ng-model-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) specifically the `debounce` property. Dunno if it will work with that directive, but you can give it a try.

Comment: Use setTimeout() , and recreate it on every click.

Comment: According to the allmighty-autocomplete docs, there is an `on-type` attribute? Have you tried it?

Comment: ya i have used on-type property but i want to execute my fuction once typing has been stopped

Comment: You can possibly set a timeout in the function you are executing on the `on-type` event. It will get restarted every time the user types but won't if they stop typing.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) and [`ng-model-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) (Angular 1.3+ only):

```
<input type="text"
       ng-model="myVar"
       ng-model-options="{debounce: 1000}"
       ng-change="functionToBeCalled()"/>
```

Comment: @RajDubey "*This doesn't work*" does not mean anything. What is the behavior? Do you have any error? What is your Angular version?

Comment: actually by using this what i do is just delay the response. but what I want is when user is typing there should be a loader and it stops typing options are shown