# How to make md-search-text-change wait for 1000ms before firing a call?

Tags: angular-material, md-autocomplete

Presently, the md-search-text-change event fires a  call every time I type something in . I want to delay this. I've tried using debounce. But that has not worked.

Comment: Check if this post is helping you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43048970/execute-a-function-when-user-has-stopped-typing-in-angularjs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the 'md-delay' attribute of md-autocomplete to achieve this. look at the documentation for more help:

https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.5/api/directive/mdAutocomplete

Answer (score 0):

the best way of doing so is by using AngularJs md-autocomplete directives. You just need to add `md-delay=""` and/or `md-min-length=""` (in case you want to start searching after a certain input length).

Hope it helped though a bit late.